# Hexadecimal array in pointer

Tags: c

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    char p[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};
    int *q = p;
    printf("%x",*q);
    return 0;

  }
```

When I run the above code, the answer is 4030201. Why?

Comment: "Why?" Because you got unlucky. Had the code printed 'UB detected. Please ask on SO why' you had got lucky!

Comment: `int *q = p;` is illegal in C. Your compiler told you about it. The rest is just experiments with undefined code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you compile and run your code on little-endian architecture machine (x86 for example)

At first you put 4 bytes in memory in order: `01 02 03 04`. Than convert pointer to this array to pointer to int. On little-endian machine memory block `01 02 03 04` represents integer value 0x04030201 which is printed on next step.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for more information