# Is type punning via union pointer legal in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, type-punning

This question is inspired by [the code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58257938/1717300), copied below, which does illegal type punning via pointer:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char p[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};
    int *q = p;
    printf("%x",*q);
    return 0;
}
```

---

My question is, is the following version of above code legal? *I am most unsure about casting pointer to char to pointer to union containing char array.* Plenty of questions about type punning here at SO, but I did not find a duplicate which covers using a pointer in this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union char_int {
    char p[4];
    int32_t q;
};

int main()
{
    char p[]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};
    int *q = &(((union char_int *)p)->q);
    printf("%x",*q);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Related, I believe these bytes will form a legal `int32_t` value for all possible representations allowed by the standard, but if someone can confirm this extra detail, that'd be great too.

Comment: The behavior of `(union char_int *)p` is in general not defined by the C standard due to C 2018 6.3.2.3 7: “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…“ if `p` happens to be aligned as needed for a `union char_int`, then the standard says “when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.” The standard does not say that this pointer actually has any value that works as a `union char_int *` in any other way.

Comment: In other words, if we have `union char_int *x = (union char_int *) p;`, and that is successful because the alignment happens to work, the standard says nothing about the **value** of `x` other than `(char *) x` produces something that compares equal to `p`. The value of `x` is not necessarily a valid address otherwise—`*x` could refer to entirely different memory than `p`, for example.

Comment: Is not really a question of legal or illegal, but rather undefined behaviour. The first is results in undefined behaviour due to violation of strict aliasing. Both result in undefined behaviour due to the value of `*q` being affected by the implementation's underlying integer representation (mostly endianness, but potentially the platform may not use 2s complement). And as pointed out above both are undefined due to aligment.

Comment: @Graeme: Variations due to endianness are implementation-defined, not undefined. The standard requires implementations to document their memory representations, in C 2018 6.2.6.1 2: “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.” After the pointer conversion issues, it is the aliasing that is the problem, not the representation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Related, am I imagining, or was there some language about address of struct being castable to address of its first element type? Of course here we have `union` and we are not casting *from* its address anyway, so that says nothing about this case.

Comment: @hyde: Yes, that is in C 2018 6.7.2.1 15 (for structures) and 16 (for unions): “… A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa…” and “… A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types..." depends upon how one defines the words "object" and "by" as used in that rule.  So far as I can tell, there has never been anything resembling consensus on what those words mean, beyond the fact that the authors of the Standard presumably expected implementations to try to interpret the rule sensibly.  Note that under a literal interpretation of the rule, something like:

```
short volatile x;
int test(void)
{
  int y = x+1;
  return y;
}
```

would invoke UB because the lifetime of y begins when code enters `test`, which in turn happens before `x` is read, but it cannot receive a value until after `x` is read.  Consequently, the value of `y` must change within its lifetime, but such action does not involve any lvalue expression of type `int` nor any other allowable type.

Clearly such an interpretation would be absurd, but a rule that omits straightforward cases on the presumption that implementations will know what to do can't be relied upon to consider more complicated ones.  With regard to the construct at issue, some compilers would say that in an lvalue expression like `someUnion.member = 23;`, the union object is modified "by" the lvalue expression `someUnion`, but not necessarily make allowances for the possibility that such an object might be accessed elsewhere by an lvalue of member type, nor by lvalues of other union types containing the same member.  Without any clarity on what the word "by" is supposed to mean, however, it's not really possible to characterize any particular interpretation as right or wrong.

Comment: the strict aliasing rule is straitforward, in the expression `int y = x+1;` there is no strict aliasing violation as the stored value of object `y` is not accessed by a type not allowed by the rule. The talking about lifetime and when the variable begins its lifetime and when it gets assigned is your interpretation, the standard does not say they relate, and I don't see how your example is UB. It seems your explanation forces a non existence connection between the lifetime and strict aliasing, but I'll be glad to learn something new if you can add some explanation

Comment: @user2162550: The rule as written doesn't merely forbid access by lvalues of other types, but by anything that isn't an lvalue of proper type.  A proper fix would be to limit the rule to objects which have been previously accessed within the same context as the lvalue access, and require that the lvalue used for access be visibly associated with the earlier object within that context.  When executing expression like `someUnion.arrayMember[i]=x;`, the access is performed with an lvalue that is visibly derived from `someUnion`, but I wouldn't say that it's accessed "by" the lvalue `someUnion`.

Comment: @user2162550: I don't think anyone would have argued before the C89 Committee that compiler writers should be entitled to willfully ignore actions which form a pointer to an object and immediately use it in the context of its formation, but neither clang nor gcc will reliably handle such operations except when using the `[]` operator.  Even `(*((someUnion.arrayMember)+(i)))` is not recognized as an access to `someUnion` or its other members, even though that expression is the very *definition* of `someUnion.arrayMember[i]` [literally!].

Comment: you say that `(*((someUnion.arrayMember)+(i)))` s not recognized as an access to someUnion or its other members, can you please share the relevant section for that? do you mean that the part of `someUnion.arrayMember` inside `(*((someUnion.arrayMember)+(i)))` is not lvalue? this is news for me

Comment: @user2162550: Neither clang nor gcc reliably recognize `(*((someUnion.arrayMember)+(i)))` as an access to `someUnion`.  The expression `someUnion.arrayMember` is an lvalue, but when it's the left-hand operator of the `[]` or `+` operator it is decomposed into a pointer "non-l" value that identifies the first element of an array rather than accessing the object.